# Could not find file or assembly "System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok en=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" when called Repl

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uitest

When I try called `.Repl()` to see view tree I get the following exception:
`Could not find file or assembly "System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok en=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"`

Nuget packages versions:

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk - 17.6.3
- NUnit - 3.13.3
- Xamarin.UITest - 4.1.4
- NUnit3TestAdapter - 4.5.0

I've already tried to google it, change versions of Xamarin.UITest and debug test

Comment: System.Runtime is Net/Core.  I would create a new console project the uses System.Runtime and see if that builds.  If it does then open the csproj file with notepad and check the version of Runtime.  You can then edit the failed csproj file and use the correct version.  What target are you using?  You may not have the version of Net/Core installed.  Also try a clean built which will get all the files recompiled.  You may of changed net versions and the intermediate obj files did not get recompiled.